# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function on all but one methods

Tags: php

I get a call to undefined function error on renderConfirm() method and any new method I try to add. But the renderData() method works fine, even if I rename it.
Code:

```
interface FieldRenderer {

    public function renderData($data, $element);

    public function renderConfirm($data, $element);
}

abstract class StdConfirmRenderer implements FieldRenderer {

    abstract public function renderData($data, $element);

    public function renderConfirm($data, $element) {
        $text = new DOMText($data);
        $element->parentNode->insertBefore($text, $element);
        $element->parentNode->removeChild($element);
    }
}

class TxtFieldRenderer extends StdConfirmRenderer {

    public function renderData($data, $element) {
        $element->setAttribute("value", $data);
    }
}
```

I am calling it from another class like so:

```
switch ($mode) {
        case 'data':
            $this->renderer->renderData($this->data->value, $this->data->element);
            break;
        case 'confirm':
            $this->renderer-renderConfirm($this->data->value, $this->data->element);
    }
```

As stated the renderData() works fine. the renderConfirm() and any other method I now add doesn't.


I have tried removing all inheritance, moving the inherited functions directly into the TxtFieldRenderer class and such. Still no joy.
Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Comment: It must be like `$this->renderer->renderConfirm`. You forget `>`

Comment: Ima go jump of a bridge... my linter must have bugged out...
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As Hakan SONMEZ pointed out.
I'm just blind and missed a `>`